# Writing a triple integral as a single integral

Tags: integration, volume

I need to write the following integral as a single integral. Not sure how to do it. I did manage to make it a double integral by having $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

The domain is:
$V=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, x\geq 0\}$

The integral to be calculated on this domain:
$$\iiint f(z)dxdydz=\int f(z)\square dz$$

I need to find $\square$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the first step is to write it in cylindrical coordinates:
$$
\iiint f(z) dxdydz
  = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{2r} r f(z) dzdrd\theta
  = 2\pi \int_0^1 \int_0^{2r} r f(z) dz dr,
$$
and now change the order of integration so you integrate $dz$ first.

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't $\theta$ go from $-\frac \pi 2$ to $\frac \pi 2$?

Comment: @Whyka not really, or you have to vary $r$ from $-1$ to $1$...

Comment: But $x\geq 0$...

Comment: @Whyka did not see that constraint, sorry...

Comment: Okay, thanks :)